# Prove that there is bijection between sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I need to prove that there is a bijection between these sets:
$$A = [0, 1], B = (0, 1/2) ∪ (1/2, 1)$$
I tried to use Cantor–Bernstein–Schroeder theorem but I am lost. 
Can you help me?

Comment: See that $(0,1/2)\cup(1/2,1)=(0,1)\setminus\{1/2\}=[0,1]\setminus \{0,1,1/2\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $B$ already sits inside $A$. Now shrink $A$ enough and then translate it a bit to the right so it fits inside $(0,1/2)$.

Comment: what do you mean by translating it to the right?

Comment: $x\mapsto x+c$ for a suitably chosen $c>0$.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** You can actually find an explicit bijection between the two sets.

Let $x_n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+2}}$ for $n\in\Bbb N$. Now consider a map shifting the $x_n$'s around so that you can put all the three missing point into the gap.

(This is somewhat similar to the proof that $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1,2\}$ has a bijection between them.)

Comment: can you give me bijection between these sets?

Comment: I gave you a hint. You can't think about a bijection between $\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\setminus\{0,1,2\}$?

Comment: i am lost, maybe a link to proof of bijection between N and N∖{0,1,2} would help..

Comment: If you're lost, take a break for a bit, then start over. Coming up with a bijection like that on your own is shouldn't be very difficult. If you've seen the Cantor-Bernstein theorem, then you should have seen a couple of similar bijections before.